# Extracting elements from a NumPy array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that looks as follows:

```
array([
      [[[0.08467145],
         [0.0846905 ]]],
       [[[0.08470057],
         [0.08483638]]],
       [[[0.0846846 ],
         [0.08471105]]],
       [[[0.08469571],
         [0.08472978]]]], dtype=float32)
```

I want to extract the first element from each pair and store in a list and also extract the second element and store it in another list. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use array indexing with `np.ndarray.flatten`:

```py
print(a[:,:,0].flatten())
print(a[:,:,1].flatten())
```

This outputs:

```py
[0.08467145 0.08470057 0.0846846  0.08469571]
[0.0846905  0.08483638 0.08471105 0.08472978]
```